# Dell laptop boot up failure after trying to install linux and windows to dual boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, laptop

I'm new so I'm not sure if this is the place to ask this kind of question but I hope you can help! (I don't have any computer knowledge)

Basically I have a Dell laptop. I bought this laptop with windows installed and needed Linux on it as well. So I had no idea what I was doing really but I wanted to dual boot windows and Linux and it went badly wrong, I think I may ave wiped both operating systems because I can't boot up. Ever since this happened (6-7 months ago its been sitting on my desk) I'm wondering if any of you can help me with this problem:

So when I boot in up The Dell logo comes on and then a purple Ubuntu start page. I have the options 'Ubuntu' 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' 'system setup'

When I click Ubuntu, it then says [hardware error] and lots of of writing i do not understand:

```
[hardware error] CPU 0:Machine CHeck: 0 Bank 6: ee20000000
[hardware error] TSC 0 ADDR fef1ce80 Misc 43880014086
[hardware error] Processor 0:806e9 TIME 1544385082 Socket 0
```

Now I'm no expert but this looks pretty bad. Is it the end for this laptop or is there something i can do?

Comment: Create a Windows boot DVD/USB an reinstall.

Comment: Thanks so what steps would this require. I have a working laptop, a usb, money and little comuter knowledge.

Comment: Just google for it. There are hundreds of articles about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So have you tried booting from your USB from which you installed Ubuntu? I would suggest doing this. Boot from your USB which you installed Ubuntu on and select "Try Ubuntu." From there, open up a terminal in the Dash.

Type these commands or paste into a terminal to install Boot Repair.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
boot-repair
```

I think you may have started using Linux with Ubuntu because of the word that in Ubuntu you never have to use the terminal. However, the terminal is your friend. And just in case you don't know what these commands do, I'll give you a quick rundown. The first command adds a new repository to your list of repositories. Repositories (or repos) host applications that you can install in the form of packages. The second line updates your list of repos so you can install from them later. The second to last command, as you may expect, actually installs the application Boot Repair. The last command starts the application. The apt-get at the beginning of each line is your package manager, and the sudo means "superuser do," which means you're running the command as root, which is basically equivalent to the administrator account in Windows.

After you run the last command, you will see a screen pop up after a few minutes and click on "Recommended Repair." This will repair it; it will prompt you to upload the results of the repair to a pastebin; click yes as this will help diagnose any further problems with boot and problems that Boot Repair found. When it is done, take a breath and reboot your computer, and this should work.